# Adding HTML table rows and columns using Javascript Array , not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with HTML table and JS array. I have table header and last row of Subtotal.

I have tried to create and add rows with the code below but it's not working. The code should read the array elements and should create rows as per the number of elements and then add columns to it as well.

Help me please!

```js
 var titles = ["Book 1","Book 2","Book 3"];
        var quantities = [3,1,2];
        var prices = [80,125,75];
        var GrandTotal = 0;

        function myTable() {
            for(var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
                var x = document.createElement("TR");
                x.setAttribute("id", "myTr[i]");
                document.getElementById("table").appendChild(x);
                
                for(var j=0;titles.length;j++){
                    //creating Title columns
                    var titleColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var titleColumnText = document.createTextNode(titles[j]);
                    
                    //adding title values
                    titleColumn.appendChild(titleColumnText);
                    document.getElementById("myTr[i]").appendChild(titleColumn);
                    
                    //creating Quantity columns
                    var qtyColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var qtyColumnText = document.createTextNode(quantities[j]);
                                        
                    //adding Quantity values
                    qtyColumn.appendChild(qtyColumnText);
                    document.getElementById("myTr[i]").appendChild(qtyColumn);
                    
                    //creating Price columns
                    var priceColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var priceColumnText = document.createTextNode(prices[j]);

                    //adding Price values
                    priceColumn.appendChild(priceColumnText);
                    document.getElementById("myTr[i]").appendChild(priceColumn);

                    // Amount calculation
                    var amt=prices[j]*quantities[j];

                    //creating Amt columns
                    var amtColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var amtColumnText = document.createTextNode(amt);

                    //adding Amt values
                    priceColumn.appendChild(amtColumnText);
                    document.getElementById("myTr[i]").appendChild(amtColumn);

                    GrandTotal += amt;
                }
            }    
        }

        document.getElementById("grandTotal").innerHTML= GrandTotal;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <title>Table and Array</title>
    <style>
    table{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, tr, td{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body ">
<div class="title">
    <h1>My Store</h1>
</div>
<table class="table-fill" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Product Title</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">I want to add rows anc columns here dynamically</td>
        </tr>        
        <tr class="totals">
            <td colspan="4" id="subTotal">Subtotal</td>
            <td id="grandTotal"></td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="js/data.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: GrandTotal is not defined error please correct the code first

Comment: yeah I saw that too.. but that's not the main problem...

Comment: for me to go through the code or anyone  you have to make it run first man

Comment: it is running.. but only the HTML code.. the JS is not coming into picture...

Comment: You are not running the function man

Comment: posted a code below it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />        
    <title>Table and Array</title>
    <style>
    table{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, tr, td{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body ">
<div class="title">
    <h1>My Store</h1>
</div>
<table class="table-fill" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Product Title</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">I want to add rows anc columns here dynamically</td>
        </tr>        
        <tr class="totals">
            <td colspan="4" id="subTotal">Subtotal</td>
            <td id="grandTotal"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
<script>

 var titles = ["Book 1","Book 2","Book 3"];
        var quantities = [3,1,2];
        var prices = [80,125,75];
        var GrandTotal = 0;

        function myTable() {
            console.log('a')
            for(var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
                var x = document.createElement("TR");
                x.setAttribute("id", `${titles[i]}`);
                document.getElementById("table").appendChild(x);
                console.log(document.getElementById("table"))
                    //creating Title columns
                    var titleColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var titleColumnText = document.createTextNode(titles[i]);

                    //adding title values
                    titleColumn.appendChild(titleColumnText);
                    console.log(document.getElementById(`${titles[i]}, ${titles[i]}`))
                    document.getElementById(`${titles[i]}`).appendChild(titleColumn);

                    //creating Quantity columns
                    var qtyColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var qtyColumnText = document.createTextNode(quantities[i]);

                    //adding Quantity values
                    qtyColumn.appendChild(qtyColumnText);
                    document.getElementById(`${titles[i]}`).appendChild(qtyColumn);

                    //creating Price columns
                    var priceColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var priceColumnText = document.createTextNode(prices[i]);

                    //adding Price values
                    priceColumn.appendChild(priceColumnText);
                    document.getElementById(`${titles[i]}`).appendChild(priceColumn);

                    // Amount calculation
                    var amt=prices[i]*quantities[i];

                    //creating Amt columns
                    var amtColumn = document.createElement("TD");
                    var amtColumnText = document.createTextNode(amt);

                    //adding Amt values
                    amtColumn.appendChild(amtColumnText);
                    document.getElementById(`${titles[i]}`).appendChild(amtColumn);

                    GrandTotal += amt;
            }    
        }
        myTable();
        var grandTotalText = document.createTextNode(GrandTotal);
        document.getElementById("grandTotal").appendChild(grandTotalText)
</script>
</html>
```